# What's the best way to change the youtube player size after mouseover?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to create a zoom effect when mousing over a youtube player (iframe) .

Currently I am using the YouTube IFrame Player API to construct the player and triggering an onmouseover event listener to adjust the size of the player upon mousing over the player. And it doesn't seem to be working.

http://plnkr.co/edit/TOtWD9?p=preview

```
function zoom() {
       player.setSize(width=200, height=150);
      }
      document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('onmouseover', zoom);
```

Any ideas on how to get this running or other approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I clicked the plnkr link that you provided and picked up on a couple of issues that you have with your code, hence you are failing to achieve the anticipated / desired results:

```
I modified your code as follows:

HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  </head>

  <body>

  <div id="playerHolder"></div><div id="player">stage1</div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Feedback:
    Unless you know what you are doing, in terms of what to do with js when certain things have happened ( "load order" ), put js last as you are not doing a check if the DOM element ( "player / playerHolder") has loaded before you bind it to any events. This helps prevent errors relating to undefined / null objects being bound to events.

```
css:

/* Styles go here */
body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#playerHolder{
  border:2px solid red;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}

Feedback:

The reason for what I did ( may not be the only way to do it ) is to set perspective "over" the YouTube embed. Note that, as far as I know, you cannot modify third party code from your server, in other words, unless there's a API function that allows you to add custom code, such as you binding a hover event onto the YouTube player, you can't just do it.

js:


      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'SjOLOfyn95U',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          //setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }

      function zoom() {
       player.setSize(width=200, height=150);
      }
      document.getElementById('playerHolder').addEventListener('mouseover', zoom, false);
```

Feedback:

```
1) You targeted the Video embed itself, which I explained the issues relating to that on the css section above.
2) You used 'onmouseover', which I replaced with 'mouseover'


I hope this helps solve your problem.
```